# Kafka connector tasks remain in unassigned state permanently

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka connect cluster with > 500 connectors (custom). At times a chunk of the tasks go into "unassigned" state (> 50) and just stay there. At what conditions does this happen and is there any way to figure out why it stays in unassigned ?

This is on kafka connect version 2.4.1. I saw this [When does a task in a connector move to unassigned state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406400/when-does-a-task-in-a-connector-move-to-unassigned-state) but don't see any reason that would apply here

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Dude0001 Never did, we sometimes see that even after upgrading to kafka connect 3.2. We just have a cron job which detects and restarts them every few minutes

Answer (score 1):

For the version of Kafka Connect mentioned in the question (2.4.1), this could be [KAFKA-9472](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9472).

On older versions of Kafka Connect, if the number of tasks for a connector was reduced, the deleted tasks would appear as `UNASSIGNED` in the REST API instead of being removed. A patch was merged in May 2020 and the 2.3.2, 2.4.2, 2.5.1, and 2.6.0 (and beyond) releases should not have this issue any more.

For later versions of Kafka (since you mentioned in a comment that this persists after upgrading to 3.2.x), it's difficult to say for certain without more information. If you have log files of the time leading up to these tasks going into the `UNASSIGNED` state to share, we might be able to discern a root cause. One possibility is that there's churn in the cluster and the [scheduled rebalance delay](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connectconfigs_scheduled.rebalance.max.delay.ms) is kicking in, but with the default value for that property, that should automatically resolve after five minutes.